# Seal crack between brick wall and drywall

Tags: drywall, crack

I've had an extension done a year ago and the builder did a wonderful job, but now after the winter the drywall is pulling away from the brick wall and there is a slight crack. The brick wall has been plastered and painted as well, just for the record.

I can paint it over but the crack will reappear, so I'm thinking about something more elastic. What is the best way to fix this?
Would silicone work? Or what about gloss paint, does that have enough elasticity in it?

This question is slightly different from [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16759/20614) which is more about a ceiling.

Comment: caulk. If you want to paint over it, be sure to choose a paintable caulk (many silicones are not)

Comment: @Ecnerwal sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a caulk might not fix your problem....Crack might appear next winter. You should use tape specially designed for dry wall joints it looks like this:[image]

After that you can paint the wall. Of course, you use this tape with caulk like products, specially for this purpose (knauf-fugenfuller etc.)

Comment: Looks like a good option. Any idea what the name of this tape is?

Comment: Course I do but in my language :) I found English translation: "flange" but I don't think it's a good one, since when I told it to someone he didn't knew what I was speaking about. I'll try to get a better translation. Anyway it is usual drywall material.

Comment: It looks like a search for `Joint Tape` and `Wall Repair Tape` brings it up online.

Comment: The best translation I have found is coverstrip....but like I told you anyone who is working with drywalls knows what is it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't fill in the gap between drywall in brick.  Caulk, mud, plaster, whatever will not keep this area from having problems.  I have done tons of drywall to brick and there is simply a small gap there.  Anything else doesn't look right.

I have also seen small t-molding placed there and it looks... OK but not right.

I have seen caulk and it just looks bad because the brick isn't a flat edge against the drywall.  It has valleys for mortar and these take a lot of extra caulk.

Then you can plaster over the entire brick or backer board to get rid of gap but you are losing the brick.

I have brick fireplace right next to custom shelving in my house and really glad I didn't caulk it.  The key for your situation is a nice straight thin drywall line.

Comment: Good answer, although I failed to fully explain the wall is already plastered and painted. I'll update my question.